# Pass Type into function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

In Swift you can pass a type into a function like so:

```
func foo<T>(_ type: T.Type)

foo(String.self)
```

Is there any equivalent in Kotlin?
I don't want to specify the type in the generic arguments, because there are multiple generic arguments and it would be annoying to have to specify them all when the compiler can work it out itself except for this one. Also I don't want to use KClass as that requires the type to by Any which I don't want to make a requirement for the type.

Comment: It would be better, if you specified the use case. there might be a better option then the one that simply tries to imitate swift

Answer (score 0):

you can you `class.java.typeName`

```
/**
 * Return an informative string for the name of this type.
 *
 * @return an informative string for the name of this type
 * @since 1.8
 */
public String getTypeName() {
    if (isArray()) {
        try {
            Class<?> cl = this;
            int dimensions = 0;
            do {
                dimensions++;
                cl = cl.getComponentType();
            } while (cl.isArray());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(cl.getName());
            for (int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++) {
                sb.append("[]");
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (Throwable e) { /*FALLTHRU*/ }
    }
    return getName();
}
```

```
foo(Int::class.java.typeName)
foo(String::class.java.typeName)
```